# Linkedin API . We can get the mail user's friends? Or LinkedIn forbids it?

Tags: api, linkedin-api, hello.js

I'm trying to get access to the user's contacts. I need the name and e-mail. But I can only get a name. LinkedIn does not allow politics to get even and emails? I use sdk hello.js

Comment: If you found the answer helpful you should upvote/accept it. This is how SO works + it's common courtesy. Otherwise you'll find yourself not getting answers to your questions in the near future. Do you understand?

Comment: @sebster Hi. I tried to vote for the answer, but I could not.It throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like linked in has removed the ability to get this field, though I think at some time in the past it was possible:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/contact

Comment: Thanks) I found the official permission of data that we can get)
https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api